# How to force bash to use values within a variable literally?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a bash script that will temporarily store a string and uses it later within a command. The issue is that a lot of times the string will have `!` or other non-alphanumerical characters and bash will then take them literally and does what bash would usually do with these characters.

So for the example of `!`, it will try to run a command by doing History Substitution. I know that for that specific case I can just start the script with `#!/bin/bash +H`, but I can't really account for all the possible characters, so how can I make bash use the values within a variable literally?

For example:

```
var=u134y123!3q54wtgf..314/sa|asd
/path/to/command -option $var
```

In this above case, how would I make it so bash doesn't think I'm doing History Substitution or I/O Redirection (due to the `|`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about quoting. [Single-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217074/108618) [`!`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33340/108618) and `|` to store them literally. [Double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) `$var`.

```
var='u134y123!3q54wtgf..314/sa|asd'
/path/to/command -option "$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I do understand you correctly. To me it seems

```
var="u134y123ls -laq54wtgf..314/sa|asd"
echo "$var"
```

does the trick. Output:

```
u134y123ls -laq54wtgf..314/sa|asd
```