# Convert multi lines to single line with spaces and quotes

Tags: shell, text-processing

How can I convert multi lines to a single line with spaces and quotes
using `awk` or `tr` or any other tool which makes it simple
(but not `for` loops)?

```
$ cat databases.txt
Wp_new
Frontend DB
DB_EXT
```

Expected:

```
$ cat databases.txt
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

Edit 1:

> Thanks for all the useful answers. But the one I marked as correct is
> the one which can be typed on terminal in short time and with fewer hassles (simplicity)
> so that I(syadmins) can do the operations very fast without making the systems downtime more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `sed + paste`

```
$ sed 's/.*/"&"/' databases.txt
"Wp_new"
"Frontend DB"
"DB_EXT"

$ sed 's/.*/"&"/' databases.txt | paste -sd' ' -
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

Or, just `paste` (courtesy https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593240)

```
$ <databases.txt paste -d '"' /dev/null - /dev/null | paste -sd' ' -
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

---

If input has empty lines that should be ignored:

```
$ cat ip.txt
Wp_new

Frontend DB



DB_EXT
$ sed -n 's/..*/"&"/p' ip.txt | paste -sd' ' -
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

Answer (score 13):

It can be done with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '{printf("\"%s\" ",$0)} END { printf "\n" }' databases.txt
```

Output:

```
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

Comment: @roaima please post your solution as an answer :)

Comment: @roaima thanks updated.

Comment: @roaima Adding `printf "\n"` is wrong. It doesn't solve the trailing blank problem and it's hard-coding the value you hope `ORS` will have (`\n`) instead of simply using `ORS` as would occur if you used `print ""` instead of `printf "\n"`. If the OP cares about an added blank or a mising newline then the right way to do this with awk is what I show at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594059/133219 - use the value `OFS` as appropriate and end with the value of `ORS` as appropriate.

Comment: @EdMorton we're joining lines as quoted words with a trailing newline. What other value of ORS were you considering!?

Comment: @roaima `\r\n` and `\0` are common ones that come to mind but beyond that philosophically - awk has a variable `ORS` that contains the value of the record terminator, any time you have a variable for a specific purpose writing code that then hardcodes the value of that variable is generally bad, especially if it's lengthier code (`printf "\n"`) than code that just uses the variable (`print ""`).

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s\"%s\"", sep, $0; sep=OFS} END{print ""}' file
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways of achieving the result using `sed`. Here are two solutions:

```
$ sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' infile | sed ':a;{N;s/\n/ /;ba}'
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

or

```
$ sed 's/.*/"&"/' infile | sed ':a;{N;s/\n/ /;ba}'
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

First, double quotes are added to the start and end of each text line, then the text lines are joined together.

Comment: I always prefer  ```sed``` over ```awk```. thank you.

Comment: (1) Your `sed` command with the ```N;s/\n/ /;ba``` ends up with the entire input file (plus the added quotes) in the pattern space (i.e., it treats it as one very long line), right? (Or am I misreading it?) While GNU `sed` seems to allow the pattern space to grow as large as it can get with dynamically allocated memory, [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) specifies only that the pattern space be able to handle 8192 bytes, so this might fail on non-GNU systems. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) I believe that you don’t need the braces in that `sed` command — ```:a; N; s/\n/ /; ba``` seems to work.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'   Yes the braces are optional in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

`GNU xargs`

```
<databases.txt xargs -d'\n' printf '"%s"\n' | paste -sd\  ;
```

Or we can use perl also:

```
perl -l40 -012 -pe 's/^|$/"/g;$\=$/ if eof' databases.txt
```

**Results**:

```
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be done in some sed with:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/" "/g;s/.*/"&"/' databases.txt 

"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "" "DB_EXT" "" "empty"
```

Or, if you don't like branch and branch labels:

```
$ sed -n '/^$/!{                                          
    ${H;x;s/\n/" "/g;s/.*/"&"/;p;d;}
    $!{H;1h}
    }' databases.txt 

"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT" "empty"
```

But both load the whole file into memory, which could use a lot for long files.

With some help from paste, sed could read lines one-at-a-time:

```
$ sed 's/.*/"&"/' databases.txt | paste -sd ' '

"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "" "DB_EXT" "" "empty"
```

There is no need for the usual '-' for paste as it reads from stdin by default when given no FILE.

It could also be done in awk with explicit values:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{dq="\""; sp=""} {
     printf "%s%s%s%s", sp, dq, $0,dq; sp=" "
     }END{print ""}' databases.txt 

"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

Comment: Kudos for using the `&` replacement!  :)

Comment: Thx for the explanation regarding the usual  ending ' -' for paste in your last example!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another `sed` solution. 
Inevitably, it has some overlap
with the answers by [fpmurphy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/593993/80216#594109) and [Sundeep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/593993/80216#594127).

```
{ sed 's/.*/"&"/; 1!s/^/ /' databases.txt | tr -d '\n'; echo;}
```

- Wrap each line in quotes.
- Add a space ***to the beginning*** of every line but the first.
- Delete all newlines.
- Add a newline at the end.

As Sundeep points out,
you can move `< databases.txt` to the beginning of the command
if you particularly prefer to see the input specification in that position
(rather than in the middle of the command). 
And you can replace the `echo` with `printf '\n'` —
although, following up on [Ed Morton’s comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/593993/80216#comment1108626_593997),
`echo` might do a better job of generating the appropriate
end-of-line character(s) in something other than a pure Unix/Linux context
(e.g., a Windows/GNU hybrid).

Answer (score 1):

I love to use `tr(1)` to convert mult line strings into single line strings first and then work on them via `sed(1)` by first inserting the trailing and initial quote, then replacing all 'internal' semicolons, i.e.:

```
$ cat databases.txt | tr '\n' ';' | sed 's/;$/"\n/; s/^/"/; s/;/" "/g'
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```

Of course you can choose any other character than `;`, as long as it isn't contained in the the input itself.

While this should be easy to reason about, it is *not* necessarily portable and definitely not POSIX as correctly pointed out by @g-man-says-reinstate-monica.  The issue lies in sed needing to read the whole line---here the entire file---while POSIX only requiring 8192 byte lines ([1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)).  Additionally, the input to sed must be a file (i.e. end with a newline [2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206)).

I want to leave this trick here as it's still convenient if the above restrictions do not apply, however I want to stress it shouldn't be used as part of a script :)

Comment: what if file has already ```;```  in lines ?

Comment: @AkhilJ '[...] as long as it isn't contained in the the input itself.' More often than not I find myself in the situation that there's one character that is not in any of the lines, thus enabling me to use this simple solution. I acknowledge however, that it's not universally applicable.

Comment: The good news is this seems to work in GNU/Linux (i.e., using GNU ``sed``) and that it contains an arguably clever(?) trick not seen in the other answers. The bad news is that it’s not POSIX-compliant and, IMHO, not very clear. (1) The input to `sed` is the (entire) file, with newlines replaced by semicolons — i.e., the entire file, treated as one line, read into the pattern space all at once. (1a) While GNU `sed` seems to allow the pattern space to grow as large as it can get … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  with dynamically allocated memory, [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) specifies only that the pattern space be able to handle 8192 bytes, so this might fail on non-GNU systems for large files.  (1b) The input to `sed` does not contain *any* newlines, not even at the end.  (Obviously you understand that, as your **``s/;$/"\n/g``** command adds the required newline at the end.)  However, POSIX specifies that the *input* to `sed` must be a text file, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  which means [it must end with a newline](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403).  So, theoretically, this could fail on non-GNU systems for files of any size.  (2) This is about clarity, opinion and style.  (2a) For the three-line input in the question (or any three-line input, for that matter), there will be six quote characters in the output.  All the other answers insert them in the order 1 & 2, then 3 & 4, then 5 & 6.  Your answer inserts them in the order 6, then 1, then 2 & 3, then 4 & 5.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  This fractured pairing is what I referred to as an arguably clever trick. Absent an explanation, it is cryptic (again, IMO). (2b) Why don’t you at least do them in the order 1, then 2 & 3, then 4 & 5, then 6? I know the reason, but you should explain it. (2c) **`s`** commands that are anchored with `^` or `$` don’t need the **`g`** modifier, since they cannot be executed more than once per line. (3) UUOC.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Wow, thanks for the detailed review! I've used that on Solaris 10/11 and OpenBSD as well, but they either do more than POSIX demands (as they also handle non-\n-terminated files) or I've never had to deal with very long input (not totally unlikely as well). I'll definitely update my answer addressing your comments later this day, thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, once I start writing, I don’t know where to stop. I’m glad you appreciate my review (many people don’t). … … … … … … … … … … P.S. Have you done a search for “UUOC” yet?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' No problem! Oh, I honestly missed that, but `tr(1)` is actually one of the few UNIX programs that cannot optionally read from stdin, so you're forced to create a redirection---which in this case wouldn't really be a big benefit but (IMHO) harm readability :)

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e 'lines>>.raku.put;'
```

OR

```
raku -e 'lines.map(*.raku).put;'
```

Sample Input:

```
Wp_new
Frontend DB
DB_EXT
This "quoted" ending comment
```

Sample Output:

```
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT" "This \"quoted\" ending comment"
```

If you play with the various commands above, you'll find that the `lines` command reads input lazily (stripping newlines by default), the `raku` (or `perl`) command gives you an internal 'Perlish/Rakuish' representation of the input (i.e. adds quotes), and the `put` command means 'print-using-terminator'.

If the above code is unmemorizable and/or too long to type, you could try 'meeting-Raku-halfway' with the following code (i.e. below returns more "Rakuish" output):

```
raku -e 'lines.list.raku.put;'  databases.txt  #OP's database.txt file

("Wp_new", "Frontend DB", "DB_EXT")
```

Or more simply:

```
raku -e 'lines.raku.put;'  databases.txt  #OP's database.txt file

("Wp_new", "Frontend DB", "DB_EXT").Seq
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/lines
https://raku.org/

Comment: Note: I added the line `This "quoted" ending comment` to illustrate Raku's elegant handling of quote characters (escaping them). The accepted sed/paste answer returns the result `"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT" "This "quoted" ending comment"`.

Comment: great. looks simple. This is the first time I encountered `raku` command in text processing, and I think it's not available in POSIX like `sed`.  But I am going to use this from now. Thanks. @jubilatious1

Answer (score 0):

All answer are nice, I guess this depend about what output did you expect. If you want a raw line text with no additional characters or if is necessary to add some, I tried this and it works very nice to me:

Simply collapse the text:

```
cat yourFile | paste -sd' ' -
>item1 item2 item3
```

Surround item with double-quotes:

```
sed -n 's/..*/"&",/p' yourFile | paste -sd' ' -
>"item1", "item2", "item2",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'ORS=" "{print "\""$0"\""}' filename
```

output

```
"Wp_new" "Frontend DB" "DB_EXT"
```