# How to enclose each line in single/double quote and end with comma except for the last line should not have a comma?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to enclose these in single/double quote and ending with a comma. But I also need it so that the last line does not include the comma as it is the last record.

I've found several post of the same requirement but cannot find one that exclude the last line.

Below is the sample data I've saved into `/tmp/x`

```
ANONYMOUS
APEX_040200
APEX_PUBLIC_USER
APPQOSSYS
AUDSYS
```

Desired Output below enclosed in single quotes. May need to enclose in double quotes too later on.

```
'ANONYMOUS',
'APEX_040200',
'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
'APPQOSSYS',
'AUDSYS'
```

I am able to use the following but don't know how to make it so that the last line is in single/double quotes **but without the comma**.

```
awk '{ printf "'\''%s'\'',\n", $0 }' /tmp/x ## single-quote
awk '{ printf "\"%s\",\n", $0 }' /tmp/x ## double-quote
```

So, the output am getting is below, note the comma on the last record.

```
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",

'ANONYMOUS',
'APEX_040200',
'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
'APPQOSSYS',
```

How can I suppress the trailing `,` for the last line?

Comment: How should lines containing quotes be handled?

Comment: Are you creating a list that should be included in some particular structured document (JSON, YAML, etc.)?

Comment: You could use a variable and declare it after the first use :) I have posted an answer with the exact code^^

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v q=\' -v ORS= '{print s q $0 q; s=","RS} END{print RS}' file
'ANONYMOUS',
'APEX_040200',
'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
'APPQOSSYS',
'AUDSYS'
```

or to use double instead of single quotes just change `-v q=\'` to `-v q=\"`:

```
$ awk -v q=\" -v ORS= '{print s q $0 q; s=","RS} END{print RS}' file
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",
"AUDSYS"
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, this works fine. can i pass on a variable whether I want to use single or double quote? That way, i only need to 'remember' one of them?

Comment: My answer shows you exactly how to pass on a single or double quote in a variable so I don't understand why you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The following `awk` program should work:

```
awk 'FNR>1{printf ",\n"} {printf "\047%s\047",$0} END{printf "\n"}' input.txt
```

This will

- print a comma followed by a newline before anything else, except for when processing the first input line, to terminate the "previous line"
- print the content of the current line enclosed in single-quotes (expressed via [octal ASCII code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/593212/377345)), but *without* comma or new-line (since it doesn't know yet which will be needed)
- at end-of-file, print only a new-line, to terminate the output corresponding to the last input line

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be with AWK? sed allows checking for the last line directly (`$`), so you can remove a final comma with `$s/,$//`.

Or, in full, to both add the quotes and commas and remove the comma on the last line:

```
% sed -e "s/.*/'&',/" -e '$s/,$//' file.txt
'ANONYMOUS',
'APEX_040200',
'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
'APPQOSSYS',
'AUDSYS'
```

or, through using a shell variable to hold the quote character (so we can swap it to a single quote through using `q=\'` instead.):

```
% q=\"
% sed -e "s/.*/$q&$q,/" -e '$s/,$//' file.txt
'ANONYMOUS',
'APEX_040200',
'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
'APPQOSSYS',
'AUDSYS'
```

Comment: Why not `sed -e "s/.*/'&',/; \$s/,\$//" file` instead? That way, you only need to escape the two `$`. Or even `sed -e "s/.*/'&',/" -e '$s/,$//' file` which makes it work with any `sed` (the ability to join commands with `;` inside the sed script is a GNU thing, or at least, not a global sed thing) and removes the need for escaping.

Comment: @terdon, yes, the one with two `-e`'s makes sense. And so would something like `-e "s/.*/'&',/;"'$s/,$//'` (The semicolon works in Busybox and on my mac too, and I'm just too used to it from other programming languages to ever remember it might not be supported everywhere. Though now that I look, the POSIX text seems to say ["Editing commands other than {...}, a, b, c, i, r, t, w, :, and # can be followed by a <semicolon>, optional <blank> characters, and another editing command."](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03).)

Comment: doesn't have to be awk. it just seems to be the one 'easiest' to use, am always lost with sed. can i pass on a variable whether I want to use single or double quote?

Comment: @benbart, not really in sed, but you could use a shell variable (edited). though it's a bit icky in that the variable gets embedded in the middle of the sed code, so putting e.g. a `/` there will break the sed script

Answer (score 2):

I would use perl for this. And, since this is perl, there are many ways.

```
$ perl -lne '$k="\"$_\""; print eof ? $k : "$k,"' file
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",
"AUDSYS"
```

Which is just a condensed version of:

```
$ perl -lne 'if(eof){ print "\"$_\""} else { print "\"$_\","}' file
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",
"AUDSYS"
```

or, with the quote character in a variable (use `$q=chr(34)` instead for a double-quote):

```
$ perl -lne '$q=chr(39); print eof ? "$q$_$q" : "$q$_$q,"' file
'ANONYMOUS',
'APEX_040200',
'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
'APPQOSSYS',
'AUDSYS'
```

or

```
$ perl -lne 'if($last){print "\"$last\","} $last=$_; END{print "\"$last\""}' file
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",
"AUDSYS"
```

Or, if the file is small enough to fit in memory:

```
$ perl -007 -pe 's/^/"/;s/\n/",\n"/g; s/,\n"$/\n/; ' file
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",
"AUDSYS"
```

or

```
$ perl -007 -F'\n' -ne 'print "\""; print join("\",\n\"",@F); print "\"\n"' file
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",
"AUDSYS"
```

---

To switch between different quoting characters, you can use this, and pass the desired quoting character as the first argument:

```
## single quotes
$ perl -lne 'BEGIN{$q=$ARGV[0]; shift}if(eof){ print "$q$_$q"} else { print "$q$_$q,"}' \' file
'ANONYMOUS',
'APEX_040200',
'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
'APPQOSSYS',
'AUDSYS'

## double quote
$ perl -lne 'BEGIN{$q=$ARGV[0]; shift}if(eof){ print "$q$_$q"} else { print "$q$_$q,"}' \" file
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",
"AUDSYS"
```

So you could indeed have that as a variable:

```
$ quote1='"'
$ quote2="'"
```

And then use those:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{$q=$ARGV[0]; shift}if(eof){ print "$q$_$q"} else { print "$q$_$q,"}' "$quote1" file
```

Comment: can i pass on a variable whether I want to use single or double quote?

Comment: Sorry, @benbart, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I think benbard is asking how to modify the solution so that the quoting character used can be specified via command-line argument.

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks @AdminBee.

Comment: @benbart see updated answer for a way of choosing the quote.

Answer (score 1):

I would just pipe the output to `sed`:

```bash
awk '{ printf "\"%s\",\n", $0 }' /tmp/x | sed '$ s/.$//'
```

---

[source](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/remove-last-char-in-file)

Comment: or (simpler) just use sed alone `sed -e "s/.*/'&'/" -e '$!s/$/,/'`

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v c=','  -v q=\' 'NR>1{print a c} {a = q $0 q} END{print a}' file
Or

$ awk -v c=','  -v q=\' 'a{print a c} {a = q $0 q} END{print a}' file
```

As suggested by @ilkkachu

The above command would produce output with single quotes. To get output in double quotes use `-v q=\"` instead of `-v q=\'`.

Comment: sorry don't have raku, first time i've heard of it. presumably i can substitute perl as raku

Comment: @benbart I've not used raku. This is an awk command.

Comment: @ilkkachu Edited. Thanks.

Comment: since `printf("")` is a no-op (when `a` is empty), and `print` appends `ORS` automatically, I wonder if something like `'a { print a c }` would be clearer. Or just `NR > 1 { print a c }`, since, well, that's what we actually mean, considering that `a` can't become empty again (unless someone sets `q` to the empty string).

Comment: @ilkkachu Edited. And thanks again for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'put join ",\n", lines.map: *.subst(:global, /^ | $/, "\"");'  file 
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",
"AUDSYS"
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -e 'put join Q:b[,\n], lines.map: *.subst(:global, /^ | $/, Q:b["]);'  file
"ANONYMOUS",
"APEX_040200",
"APEX_PUBLIC_USER",
"APPQOSSYS",
"AUDSYS"
```

Above, both the zero-width beginning-of-string `^` token and the zero-width end-of-string `$` token are `subst`-ituted with a double-quote character. Adding the `:global` named-argument assures that both substitutions per line are performed. The `lines` are then `join`-ed on `",\n"` comma-newline to give the final output. *(FYI, just `join` on `","` comma if you want all your lines concatenated into one and separated by commas).*

For quoting problems Raku offers an entire sub-language called the [Q-lang](https://docs.raku.org/language/quoting) to help massage your text into its final format. Hence the `Q:b["]` *"quote-respecting-backslash-interpolation"* code above. The `Q:b[...]` format works great for inserting characters like `Q:b[\t]` tabs and `Q:b[\n]` newlines without having to add extraneous single/double- quotes.

Specifically for single-quote and double-quote problems... Raku offers a related solution. Just use the Unicode name (either `\c[APOSTROPHE]` or `\c[QUOTATION MARK]`) as below. The fewer single/double- quotes in your one-liners the more portable your code is (e.g. to Windows):

```
~$ raku -e 'put join Q:b[,\n], lines.map: *.subst(:global, /^ | $/, "\c[APOSTROPHE]");'  file
'ANONYMOUS',
'APEX_040200',
'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
'APPQOSSYS',
'AUDSYS'

#OR:

~$ raku -e 'put join Q:b[,\n], lines.map: *.subst( /^ | $/, Q:b[\c[APOSTROPHE]]);' file
'ANONYMOUS',
'APEX_040200',
'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
'APPQOSSYS',
'AUDSYS'
```

---

*[Below I try to translate @terdon's excellent Perl solutions into Raku. But hopefully the above suffices]*.

Raku only has `eof` as method call on filehandles. So an approximate (but verbose) translation of the Perl solution by @terdon is as follows:

```
~$ raku -e 'my $fh = $*ARGFILES.IO.open; for $fh.lines() { 
               put $fh.eof ?? (Q:b["] ~ $_ ~ Q:b["]) !! (Q:b["] ~ $_ ~ Q:b[",]) 
            };'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -e 'my $fh = $*ARGFILES.IO.open; put $fh.eof  \
               ?? (Q:b["] ~ $_ ~ Q:b["])   \
               !! (Q:b["] ~ $_ ~ Q:b[",])  \
            for $fh.lines();'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -e 'given $*ARGFILES.IO.open -> $fh { $fh.eof  \
               ?? put("\"" ~ $_ ~ "\"")   \
               !! put("\"" ~ $_ ~ "\",")  \
            for $fh.lines() } ;'  file
```

In Raku, the ternary operator is **Test** `??` **True** `!!` **False** , so the code scans pretty closely with the ternary Perl answer given by @terdon. Also, string-concatenation in Raku is accomplished with `~` tilde (commas work just as well). Regexes are discarded in this solution and indeed the Raku code could be more simply written with backslash escapes as `put("\"$_\"")` or similar.

@terdon provides a `-007` Perl solution which reads the entire file into memory. Raku's equivalent is `slurp`ing the file. Below zero-width `^^` beginning-of-line and `$$` end-of-line regex tokens are utilized:

```
~$ raku -e 'given slurp() {S:g/ ^^ /"/ andthen S:g/ $$ /",/ andthen S/ \,\n $ // andthen .put};'  file
```

*Probably obvious but notable anyway: save code inside the singlequotes to something like `doublequote.p6` if you want a **zero-boilerplate** script you can run (+/- making it executable).*

---

Sample Input:

```
ANONYMOUS
APEX_040200
APEX_PUBLIC_USER
APPQOSSYS
AUDSYS
```

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/eof%20-%20perlfunc
https://raku.org

Comment: Nice! If you do go for any of mine, please leave me a comment, I'd love to see how and if that sort of classic "line noise" (:P) Perl translates into Raku.

Comment: @terdon well I've tried! It's verbose but many Perl tricks can be used to make it shorter. FYI Raku's `lines` routine autochomps by default, which is why it's my initial solution (using `join` to spare the last line). I'm actually learning quite a lot of Perl here from you and others (e.g. @ilkkachu)!

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the most beautiful way I could possibly think of:

```bash
awk '{printf "%s\047%s\047", end, $0, end=",\n"}' /tmp/x
```

Basically you add the `,\n` with a variable, but you declare the variable only after the first output and use the ascii code `\047` for the `'` :)

---

Note that the above doesn't print a final newline, so it would not create a [valid text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446237/22222) as defined by POSIX. If that's a problem, use this instead:

```bash
awk '{printf "%s\047%s\047", end, $0, end=",\n"}END{print ""}' /tmp/x
```

Comment: Please note that this is basically the approach taken by @EdMorton in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/759267/377345), only that your program doesn't print a terminating newline for the last line of input (which would be considered a malformed text file in many environments). Also, should the `,` before the `end=` assignment not be a `;`?

Comment: Well yes same approach, but better looking. And it doesn't matter if it is `,` or `;` :)

Comment: This is indeed nice, but the lack of final newline is a problem. POSIX defines a [text file](https://tinyurl.com/bddtmzzv) as "*A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines*" and defines [lines](https://tinyurl.com/y2th47bz) as "*A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character.*". This means that without the final newline, this isn't a file, and some tools will not be able to deal with it. You could just add `END{print ""}` to your script to get around that.

Comment: @terdon Man I like you :)) And yeah I know, but in most cases it doesn't matter. In this case, it would improve the Quality but decrease the Beatifulness^^ But yeah you are right. Go ahead, you can edit my answer (so you get credit for that)  :)

Comment: `, end=",\n"` (leading comma) should be `; end=",\n"` (leading semicolon) in both scripts. As written `",\n"` will be passed to `printf` as an argument after it's been evaluated and YMMV with what any awk version does when `printf` gets too many arguments for the format string you provided.

Comment: Oh gosh, this is terribly obfuscated. For one, you have a variable called `end`, but used in the _front_. Also the thing Ed said about putting the assignment in the argument list. About that, I also wonder if the order of evaluation for function arguments and their side-effects is defined in AWK (IIRC, it's not in C, and e.g. GCC warns about a construct like that. I think newer languages tend to define a left-to-right order, though.)